# Having difficulties with making my processing PrintWriter and BufferedReader work

Tags: processing, bufferedreader, filewriter

So, i was able to make my code run, however i am having trouble with the highscore code. I am unable to use the bufferedreader and printwriter functions because for some reason that i am not understanding, they are not running. I want the program to compare the score to the highscore, and if the score is larger than the highscore, the highscore will be updated on a txt file. the reason the txt file is necessary is due to the fact that once the program closes, i need a method as to check for the previous highscore. I am really new to using processing and writing and reading txt files using programs, and none of the other sites and forums ive looked at have helped because they do not write the highscore variable onto a txt file. Please help, im ready to break my computer. 
EM1.score = the score accumulated over the course of the program.

```java
class High_Score {
int highscore = 0;   
PrintWriter output; //imports the writer
BufferedReader reader; //imports the reader
int state = 0; //sets the varoable for the keyboard

void scoring() {
int score = EM1.score; 
if (score > highscore) {
  highscore = score;
}
textSize(30);  
text("Your score is "+ score, 150, height/4); 
text("The current highscore is "+highscore+".", 75, height/2);
text("Try to beat it.", 200, 450);
textSize(12); 
text("Press esc to exit this page.", 225, 550);
}

void reader() {
importHS();
updateHS();
}

void updateHS() {
int score = EM1.score; 
output = createWriter("highscore.txt");  //creates the file that will be
if (highscore < score) {
highscore = score;
output.print(highscore);
output.close();
}
}

void importHS() {
reader = createReader("highscore.txt"); //reads the current highscore
if (reader == null) {
  highscore = 0;
  return;
}
String line;
try {
  line = reader.readLine();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  line = null;
}
if (line != null) {
  highscore = int(line);
  println(highscore);
}
try {
  reader.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

void type() { //allows the screen to close is esc is pressed on the keyboard
state = key;
if (key == ESC) {
  exit();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. There are only a couple of things I see slightly off:

1. you're not calling [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush()) on the writer to writes the remaining data to the file
2. checking `if (highscore < score)` in `updateHS()` is preventing the write: you don't really need this anyway since `scoring()` already checks if the current score is a highscore and updates accordingly.

Here's most of your code tweaked to write/read from disk:

```
EM1Class EM1 = new EM1Class();
High_Score hs = new High_Score();

void setup(){
   size(800,600);

   EM1.score = 500;

   hs.reader();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  hs.scoring();
  hs.updateHS();
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP)   EM1.score += 10;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) EM1.score -= 10;
}

class EM1Class{
  int score;
}
class High_Score {
  int highscore = 0;   
  PrintWriter output; //imports the writer
  BufferedReader reader; //imports the reader
  int state = 0; //sets the varoable for the keyboard

  void scoring() {
    int score = EM1.score; 
    if (score > highscore) {
      highscore = score;
    }
    textSize(30);  
    text("Your score is "+ score, 150, height/4); 
    text("The current highscore is "+highscore+".", 75, height/2);
    text("Try to beat it.", 200, 450);
    textSize(12); 
    text("Press esc to exit this page.", 225, 550);
  }

  void reader() {
    importHS();
    updateHS();
  }

  void updateHS() {
    int score = EM1.score; 
    output = createWriter("highscore.txt");  //creates the file that will be
    output.print(highscore);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
  }

  void importHS() {
    reader = createReader("highscore.txt"); //reads the current highscore
    if (reader == null) {
      highscore = 0;
      return;
    }
    String line;
    try {
      line = reader.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      line = null;
    }
    if (line != null) {
      highscore = int(line);
      println(highscore);
    }
    try {
      reader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  void type() { //allows the screen to close is esc is pressed on the keyboard
    state = key;
    if (key == ESC) {
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

There'a placeholder `EM1Class` there just so a sketch could compile.

I'm not sure the `High_Score` class should know about `EM1` directly.
You might want to refactor the code a bit and make sure it's not as tightly coupled as it currently is since you're using classes anyway.

Also check out a [Java style guide](https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md): it will help to write code that is consistent and neatly organised. It will surely pay off building the discipline to do so on the long run, but also immediately as you're code will be easier to scan/quickly read and deduce it's flow.

Another option is to use the Processing built-in [XML](https://processing.org/reference/XML.html) and [JSON](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html) functions which will make be easier to parse (and also have handy load/save functions).

```
int score = 0;
int highScore;

void setup(){
  loadHighScore();
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  text("score:"+score+"\nhighScore:"+highScore+"\n\nuse UP/DOWN\narrows",10,15);
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP)   score += 10;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) score -= 10;
  if(score > highScore) highScore = score;
}

void loadHighScore(){
  try{
    JSONObject jsonScore = loadJSONObject("highScore.json");
    highScore = jsonScore.getInt("highScore");
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error loading/parsing highScore.json");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
void saveHighScore(){
  JSONObject jsonScore = new JSONObject();
  jsonScore.setInt("highScore",highScore);
  saveJSONObject(jsonScore,"highScore.json");
}

//save on close
void exit(){
  saveHighScore();
  super.exit();
}
```